# Translating the homepage

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am quite new to translation of Drupal and cant figure to translate a the page content on the homepage.

The entire site is translate with the normal translation methods offered by Drupal.

I have translated the blocks on the homepage but the home page content always shows in English. I have already changed the homepage alias to 'home' and both translations aswel.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you on the road:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1216132